# Best FIWare architecture?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-wirecloud, fiware-cosmos

We are developing a FiWare city sensor network that:

1. Inside the sensor processes data in real time and publishes their average every N minutes to our server;
2. some server side math to do with those reported averages, which will generate new fields or averages of already reported fields (e.g. average by day);
3. In the end, there will be a Wirecloud component showing a map with the location of every sensor and a plot showing the several fields acquired, by sensor.

Aditionally, sensors can raise alarms and every server and sensor access must be secure and server database scalability it's a future concern. At the moment we have this architecture (OCB stands for Orion Context Broker):

[image]

Where the "Webservice" and "Processing" components are house made, but after reading a little bit more about FIWare components (particulary the [IOT stack](http://fiware-iot-stack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)) I've realised that there are more components that we might integrate in here.

What are you using for a solution like this? It looks fairly generic (secure attributes publish, storage, post-processing and value plot).